# Call a function when all events are done Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is there a way to run a function only after 2+ async events of a different nature have been fulfilled?

For example, you request a file with ajax, and you post a message to a web worker. When both of those caller functions have received a response you move on to your next step.

The code below is the only way I can think to do it. But it feels ugly and has global-ish variables. I would also need to know ahead of time how many events to wait for, but that can limit run-time logic in certain situations.

```
// define variables that can be referenced by multiple functions
var globalArray = [];
var numberOfAsyncCalls = 2;

// perform an ajax call
  // on finished
  listener(ajaxResponse);

// post message to web worker
  // on response
    listener(webWorkerResponse);

function listener(response){
  globalArray.push(response);
  if(globalArray.length == 2){
    // move on to next function

  }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: `listener(ajaxResponse).then(webWorkerResponse).then(doSomethingElse);`

Comment: What if I want them to run in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what `Promise.all()` is meant to do. You can pass multiple promises into `.all()` and you'll receive a promise back which resolves once all of the passed-in promises have resolved. From an [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

Comment: Completely forgot that promises can handle 2 different types of async calls. This works great thank you!